# Select value from xml in hive/spark with xpath

Tags: hadoop, xpath, hive

I have xml:

```
<info>
<infofield name "date">2022-01-01</infofield>
<infofield name "country">USA</infofield>
<infofield name "city">New York</infofield>
</info>
```

I want select "New York" with xpath, but when i am write this query:
Select xpath_string(body,'info/infofield[3]/@name') my result is - "city", how i can select "New York"?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:

```
info/infofield[3]/text()
```

If you want to be shore that if the sequence of infofields changes, you still get te city this is the better way:

```
info/infofield[@name='city']/text()
```

Comment: Thanks!The second method is ideal